# Cosa significa "in gardenia" in questa frase?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel libro *Sardegna come un'infanzia* di Elio Vittorini ho letto:

> Ci presentano bei dignitari in gardenia, dame dal ventaglio piumato, e uno che parla forte fa come da padrone di casa, comincia a svelarci segreti, ci consiglia circa le ragazze con le quali ballare, poi ci porta a bere.

Ho cercato il significato di "gardenia" nei dizionari e ho trovato che si tratta di una pianta, ma non mi sembra che questo abbia molto senso in questo contesto. Per questa ragione chiedo: qual è il significato del vocabolo "gardenia" in questa frase?

Comment: io penso che ha senso solo con quella pianta. Quella pianta veniva usata (anche tutt'ora) da alcuni come ornamento per un abito/vestito... (forse è anche un modo di dire dialettale "in gardenia")

Comment: Credo che il testo riporti "dignitari in gardenia" così come a volte si dice, ad esempio, "uomini in blu" o "donne in rosso" per indicare persone vestite con abiti blu, o rossi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Penso che si tratti proprio del fiore che, come puoi leggere sotto, nell'Ottocento cominciò  ad essere portato all'asola  delle giacche maschili  come ornamento. Oggigiorno si una quasi esclusivamente negli abiti da sposo.

> - Oggi, nelle giacche di fattura non sartoriale, l’asola sul risvolto il più delle volte è chiusa, eppure, nonostante sia resa inutilizzabile, qualcuno a volte vi infila una piccola spilla.
> - ***L’abitudine di creare quell’asola nel revers, nasce, nell’Ottocento,*** sulle giubbe, perché si potessero chiudere fino al collo. Con il passare del tempo, l’asola, diventa solamente un ornamento, utilizzato per infilarvi il gambo di qualche fiore raro e attraente. ***A fine Ottocento sbocciano [gardenie](http://tempusvitae.it/2006/04/11/il-fiore-allocchiello/) negli occhielli delle giacche di Jean Cocteau, che ne faceva arrivare una fresca ogni mattina da Londra,*** garofani verdi sui revers di Oscar Wilde e orchidee su quelli di Montesquiou.

(tempusvitae.it)
[image]

Comment: +1, ma questi tempusvitae mi sembrano un po' faciloni: «A fine Ottocento sbocciano gardenie negli occhielli delle giacche di Jean Cocteau, che ne faceva arrivare una fresca ogni mattina da Londra ...» Jean Cocteau nacque nel 1889: faceva arrivare le gardenie da Londra a dieci anni?

Comment: Non ho controllato le date di nascita dei personaggi coinvolti, ma penso vogliano sottolineare il fatto che in quel periodo comincia la moda del fiore all'occhiello (quello che ci interessa per rispondere alla domanda). E poi chissà... Cocteau era talmente eccentrico... (giusta osservazione) :))